# Eloquent: Update Value in the Database

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I cant decrease/increase the "Kontostand" (double) value by $Betrag

The $Sender and $Empfänger Models are fine, and sucessfully picked from the Database

```
public function Transfer(){
    //Models werden erstellt
    $Sender = konto::find(request('SenderID'));
    $Empfänger = self::getModelbyIBAN(request('EmpfängerIban'));

    echo $Sender;
    echo $Empfänger;

    //Überweisung wird getätigt
    self::Transfer_execute($Empfänger, $Sender, request('betrag'));


    //Überweisungen werden für jedes Konto im Kontobewegungs-table gespeichert
    self::Transfer_save($Empfänger, "-", request('betrag'));
    self::Transfer_save($Sender, "+", request('betrag'));
```

}

private function Transfer_execute($Empfänger, $Sender, $Betrag){

```
    $SenderNeuerKontostand = $Sender->kontostand - $Betrag;
    $EmpfängerNeuerKontostand = $Empfänger->kontostand + $Betrag;

    echo "neuer Kontostand Sender ";
    echo $SenderNeuerKontostand;
    echo "<br>neuer Kontostand Empfänger ";
    echo $EmpfängerNeuerKontostand;

    $Sender->kontostand = $SenderNeuerKontostand;
    $Empfänger->kontostand = $EmpfängerNeuerKontostand;


    $Sender->save();
    $Empfänger->save();
}
```

I expect the value of "kontostand" to be changed in the database at both models, but it does not happen.

EDIT:

Here is there transfer_save method.

It creates a new entry inside of another table. It works perfectly fine.

```
  private function Transfer_save($Konto, $plusminus, $Betrag){
        $kontobewegung = new kontobewegung;
        $kontobewegung->PlusOderMinus = $plusminus;
        $kontobewegung->KontoID = $Konto->ID;
        $kontobewegung->Betrag = $Betrag;

        $kontobewegung->save();
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the `Transfer_save` method please?

Comment: I added it......

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things to test.  First, are you sure there is a non-zero/non-null value attached to `request('bertag')`?  I don't know what this is, I'm used to seeing a variable injected in the method params like so:

```
public function Transfer(Request $request){ ... }
```

and then a use of that injected variable like:

```
self::Transfer_execute($Empfänger, $Sender, $request->get('betrag'));
```

If that is working for you, then the other thing might be that you are passing the old values of `$Sender` and `$Empfänger` into the final save method.  IE you may be successfully saving them in the `Transfer_execute` method, but then you are passing the original value of those two vars back into `Transfer_save`.  I don't know what the `Transfer_save` method is doing - but if it is touching the vars, they won't be what was originally saved above, but rather the vars before saving -- you didn't pass anything back into them in the transfer_execute method.

HTH